# Comparing flonum

Tags: racket, flonum

I want to define a function that would have the following properties:

```
(almost-equal? (cos (/ pi 2)) 0.0)   ; --> #t
```

For doing that I thought that I should use `flulp` in the following way:

```
(define (almost-equal? a b)
  (let [[epsilon (max (abs (flulp (* 10.0 a))) (abs (flulp (* 10.0 b))))]]
    (<= (absolute-error a b) epsilon)))
```

But it failed to pass my test. Do we have a canonical way of doing such comparison? Any advise are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `relative-error`: [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/math/base.html?q=math#%28def._%28%28lib._math%2Fbase..rkt%29._relative-error%29%29)

I can recommend this article on how to debug numerical functions:

[Practically Accurate Floating-Point Math](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~ntoronto/papers/toronto-2014cise-floating-point.pdf)
by Neil Toronto and Jay McCarthy

Comment: `(relative-error (cos (/ pi 2)) 0.0)` give me `+inf.0`. Indeed the ideal epsilon would be far more complicate because of the use of cos. Thanks to some IRC chat I realize that the epsilon depend on the calculus of the input rather than on the relative precision of the input. The best I can do is to let the user decide epsilon and add an extra argument. Ideal epsilon would be: `(absolute-error (cos (+ (flulp (/ pi 2)) (/ pi 2))) (cos (/ pi 2)))`

Comment: Thanks for the link btw

Comment: I didn't think! Since the the expected value is zero, the relative error will be `(x-0)/0 = +inf.0`. However for expected non-zero values then `relative-error` is the function to use.